# Chained async methods - tie a thread POV?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

Assuming I have this code:

```
public void AAA()
{    
    BBB(); 
}  

public async Task BBB() 
{ 
    await Task.Delay(10000); 
}
```

IMHO, in normal mode, the method `AAA` should also be `async` so that the main thread will continue its job without waiting.

But I have 2 question regarding this situation here:

1. Is it correct to say that the code above does tie a thread for 10 sec? (I suspect that the answer is yes because AAA is not async so there is no registration for continuation)
2. If so - how can I prove it via code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that the code above does tie a thread for 10 sec?

No.

`AAA` calls `BBB`, which sets up a Task and returns immediately. Since `AAA` does not `await` on `BBB`, it also returns immediately. So "your own" thread is not tied up.

The "implementation" of `Task.Delay` itself makes use of a timer instead of blocking a thread, so neither is any thread pool thread tied up for the duration of the task.

Comment: so let's go the other way : what difference would it make if AAA was async and I was awating on bbb ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No difference conceptually, but the call to `AAA` would not return immediately so one could not then use the trivial argument "see? it doesn't block". What would actually happen is that when the `Task.Delay` timer expires a thread from the thread pool would be used to run the rest of the code inside `AAA`, rather than the timer expiring and noone caring about it.

Comment: It is the implementation of Task.Delay which distract the real answer. can you answer it as if it was cpu operation for 10 sec ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If it was a CPU operation that took 10 sec then obviously a thread would need to run for 10 sec doing the operation.

Comment: Yeah but not the main thread! im talking about a situation where the main loop thread is supposed to serve the GUI , or back in the threadpool (in asp.net)....

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Ah yes, sorry for not getting the drift immediately. Yes, you would tie up a thread from the pool. But I still don't get what the question would be in that case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51623/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-jon)